# why attributes properties in layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath does not get applied?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uipangesturerecognizer

If I modified any attribute property in `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` the collectionView cell does not get modified

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //this properties does not get applied
    attributes.zIndex = 1;
    attributes.alpha = 0.5;

    return attributes;
}
```

but when moving the properties modifications to `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` it gets applied:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray *attributesArray = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes in attributesArray)
    {
        //this properties is getting applied here
        attributes.zIndex = 1;
        attributes.alpha = 0.5;

    }
    return attributesArray;
}
```

I'am applying a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on the `UICollectionView` and I want to apply these
properties on the cell I'am currently dragging.

I'am able to call layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath method while I'am dragging through calling this method:

```
[customLayoutInstance indexOfItemSelected:indexPath.row];
```

`layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` is called as long as I'am dragging but the properties does not get applied.

Answer (score 0):

you should override one more method:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{

{
```

Comment: I'am overriding it in the code above ,, but it is only getting called
once ,, and I want a method to be called as long as I'am dragging a cell

Comment: layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath is used for(for example), reloading of one special cell

Comment: this method(layoutAttributesForElementsInRect) called any time on scrolling event

Comment: If You wont to change cell frame on pan, you can use reloadItemsAtIndexPaths

Comment: I'am applying UIPanGestureRecognizer on the CollectionView and
when I drag in cell inside layoutAttributesForElementsInRect does not
get called.

Comment: reloadItemsAtIndexPaths will cancel the dragging.